# Inline SVG during Angular compile/build time

Tags: angular, svg, server-side-rendering

We have an Angular application (SSR) and I need inline some SVG icons during build time. This is mainly to reduce the hits on our node server.

We are using [angular-svg-icon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-svg-icon) which inline the SVGs on run time. I had a look into [ng-inline-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-inline-svg) which also operates during run time.

I don't want to manually add them to the HTML not to pollute the code.
Is there a way to perform this action during compile/build?

Comment: You can always use ngIf and have something like this.browser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId); in your components constructor.

Comment: @Bartando I'm not sure how this would help, would you please explain it a bit? What I need to achieve is to inline the SVG in the HTML during build time so that I save a server call used for retrieving the SVG.

Comment: Did you read this part of the [ng-inline-svg](https://github.com/arkon/ng-inline-svg)'s [readme](https://github.com/arkon/ng-inline-svg#server-side-rendering-with-angular-universal)? What are you using for SSR?

Comment: @joaoBeno Yes, I did read this part. It suggests that the SVG could be rendered on the server side which happens after receiving a request. What I need is to replace/inject the SVG during build/compile time.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using rawloader. See an example here ==>

```
// Declare my SVG here
import mySVG from '!!raw-loader!../../../assets/my-svg-file.svg';

// Use it then to assign this 
svgElement.innerHTML = mySVG ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you would need to create a custom way to parse your templates for SVG mentions, then create an intermediate html with the file injected, that the builder would the use to generate the final product.

I think you could create a small js like "`svg_aggregator.js`" and create a custom command that runs it before the ng build... In it, you would open your .html template, scan if it has svg mentions, having, you copy the file to a tmp (like "home-component.tmp.html"), then generate a new "home-component.html", with the svg injected. then the ng build runs, then, after the build, run another script (or the same, with an argument) to revert your models to their old state.

Comment: Actually, I'm working on something like this right now. I wanted to make sure no one has a better approach. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi +Osama Did you manage to create something to inline svg in the build time?

Comment: @Kamil would love to see your take on it maybe drafting your own answer?

Comment: Hi! I made `@kmaraz/replace-svg-in-html-loader` you can find in on NPM. Feel free to file an issue or email me directly.

Answer (score 0):

I made `@kmaraz/replace-svg-in-html-loader` Webpack loader to solve this problem. It is published as a NPM package so feel free to try it out.

For the installation process tou can follow README provided in the repository: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kmaraz/replace-svg-in-html-loader#getting-started

If you have any problems/questions feel free to email me directly or file an issue.